# Why is it recommended to not install additional packages in the conda base environment? What is its purpose?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've seen it said in the
[conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-environments),
[tutorials](https://medium.com/dunder-data/anaconda-is-bloated-set-up-a-lean-robust-data-science-environment-with-miniconda-and-conda-forge-b48e1ac11646),
and
[books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149190142X).
Don't install programs in the base environment. Make a separate environment and install any packages/programs you want in that. But it's never explained why. I imagine that's because intro materials don't want to muddy the waters for beginners. So let's do that here.

*Why* should one not install additional packages in their base environment? What happens? What are the risks?

Finally, what then is the purpose of the base environment? How should I use it? What is it good for?

Answer (score 3):

The basic reason is that the Python packaging system is prone to develop incompatibilities over time, particularly with local dependencies in site-packages. The packaging system isn't set up to distinguish between differing versions of the same package.

As an example, suppose you are working with a third party library like TensorFlow. You are using 1.13, say, on some projects. Now you want to upgrade to 1.14, or 2.0, for some other new projects.

Putting everything in the base environment, you now have installed a mix of TensorFlow packages from different versions and the possibility that old packages got overwritten. This is likely to lead to problems with old projects that depended on possibly now deprecated elements of the old libraries.

There are plenty of resources that go into more detail , but essentially the use of virtual environments is to mitigate the dependency management issues of the Python packaging system and keep your projects dependencies separate.

Comment: Setting up an environment for each project makes sense. But what should the base env be used for, then?

Comment: Here we're getting into opinion based but personally I'd leave the base environment alone except for major upgrades of the Anaconda distribution. Changes to individual packages like just numpy, say, I'd still handle in virtual environments.